# How to place search params in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, url-routing, friendly-url

How do I get a form to submit it's params in the url, such that the rendered page will contain the query (rails 2.3)?

Something like this:

```
example.com/search?name=john&age=25&city=atlanta
```

Simple, I know, but I'm not sure how to do it... :)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Rails. Just set the `method` attribute of the form to `GET`.

Answer (score 2):

as stated by Jimmy: make sure your form-tag looks like this:

```
<form method="get" .....>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using routing helpers to do this use:

```
search_path(:name => "John", :age => 25, :city => "atlanta")
```